# Animating Flexbox with Media Queries?

Tags: html, css, webkit, flexbox

I'm trying to create a website using flexbox, and one of the main features of the site is to hide the navigation bar, in this case the left panel in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/LyqWm/2/), when the viewport is between 480px and 1023px. Currently it works, but the animation is very jumpy and it is not clear what is happening.

Right now I am trying to use a transition in css3, but that doesn't seem to animate anything at all...

Going from this:

```
aside {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    width: 270px;
}
```

To this:

```
aside {
    display: none;
}
```

No transition happens between the two states.

How can I animate the navigation disappearing and the main growing to fit the screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transitions on the display: property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)

Comment: Please don't use the deprecated 2009 Flexbox properties without also using the standard properties.

Comment: What are the standard properties?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/

Comment: Are you referring to `display: -webkit-flex;` and `-webkit-flex-grow: 1;`? Those properties don't work....http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/LyqWm/5/

Comment: Chrome dropped prefixes with v29:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Still doesn't work....http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/LyqWm/9/

Comment: The standard properties work in Chrome.  However, what you're doing can't possibly work for reasons explained the question I already linked to.

Answer (score 0):

You can not animate Display in CSS as of today.

You can probably chain animation on some properties that can be animated. For instance the width and height of some flexboxes.

Comment: Right but to get the element to really disappear you need to use display none, just animating the height and width to 0 doesn't clear the element from the page.

Comment: You could use display:none once the width and/or height are 0.

Comment: I will try to have a look but the "display: none" would need to be used in a callback after the initial transition ends.. there is the event (browserprefix)transitionend (webkitransitionend, otransitionend etc).